# How to reduce upload time while uploading multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, electron, aws-sdk

I have an directory with small files at minimum ranges from 2000 files to 10000 files.

Currently there is no methods to directly upload folder to s3 in aws-sdk-js.

i need to recursively loop through files inside folder and upload it to s3.

I used this lines of code.

```
const PARALLEL_UPLOADS = 10;
const q = async.queue((task, callback) => {
  s3.upload({
  Bucket: 'xxx',
  Key: task.name,
  Body: fs.createReadStream(task.path)
 }, callback)
}, PARALLEL_UPLOADS);

q.drain = function() {
  console.log('all items have been processed');
};
```

I used walk npm package to recursively read files inside folder.
inside it i push files to queue.

```
  let walker = walk.walk(path);
  walker.on("file", async function(root, stat, next) {
  q.push({
     name: stat.name,
     path: root + "/" + stat.name,
 }) })
```

I tested with folder with size 108 MB but it having 2700 files in nested folder inside it.

it takes more than 45 mins to upload.

so how to reduce the time of upload ???  Advance in thanks.

Comment: Can you try with bluebirds `Promise.map(files, file => {...}, {concurrency: 10})` just to test?

Comment: @RolandStarke yes internet speed is 800 - 900kb per second

Comment: @ЕгорЛебедев i think , i am already using async package done the same thing as bluebirds's Promise.

Comment: Any other ways to upload multiple files at same time to s3 in short time ??

Comment: Sounds like the async.queue function you're using is waiting for every task to be completed before starting the next one. Try running them in parallel using something like Promise.all or the loop functions in this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-iteration

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it waits while reading file and only then send to s3

Comment: @MilanKarman i refered from here  https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#queue

Comment: Do one thing, when you are doing `q.push` add a callback as well. like `q.push(obj, ()=>{ console.log("This task is finished")});`. So that you can check if indeed it is going parallel or serial.

Comment: if you meant 900kbit/s upload speed that would result in 16min https://www.google.com/search?q=+108mb+%2F+900kbit%2Fs+

Comment: @RolandStarke ok but it takes me to more than 45 mins to upload.

Comment: @RolandStarke and if i upload 200 mb also in one shot takes only less than 3mins